# Is there a good alternative to pyspotify as far as streaming Spotify audio in Python goes?

Tags: python, spotify, libspotify

I've been trying to look for a way to create an audio stream or otherwise grab the audio file from a Spotify URL inside of Python - my search led me to `pyspotify`, but apparently it no longer works. I haven't been able to find anything so I figured I'd ask here just in case, is there any sort of alternative these days?

Currently I'm using `spotipy` to get track data and such, but it doesn't have any playback capability. I have a premium account, so if it requires my user credentials this is also not an issue.